# Runnable caller does not terminate

Tags: java

I've made a runnable which download a big file and called it in `onCreate`.

But it seems like `onCreate` is waiting for the runnable to terminate.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
private Handler Download_taskHandler = new Handler();    
Download_taskHandler.postDelayed(Download_task, 0);
```

Comment: The code you've posted seems totally irrelevant to the question - where's the Runnable?  where's the onCreate method?  How are you calling the Runnable?    e.g. When you call it, don't just call "myRunnable.run()" -  you need a Thread:  `new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new Handler();` the default constructor binds to the Looper of the current thread. So if that is created on the UI thread and then used to execute something it will run the code on the UI thread.